# Change between multiple images when hovering another div (using css sprites)

Tags: jquery, hover, css-sprites

I'm using jQuery to change between several images when I hover over another div.  The code is as follows:

```
var imgs=['img/image01.png',
    'img/image02.png',
    'img/image03.png',
    'img/image04.png'];
var $img = $('#toons');

$('#logo').on('mouseover', function() {
    var current = imgs.indexOf($img.attr('src'));
    $img.attr('src', imgs[++current] || imgs[0]);
});
```

HTML:

```
<img id="toons" src="img/image01.png" />
```

With each hover over div#logo the image changes back and forth.  While this works great, I'm wondering if I could achieve the same using CSS sprites and background-images in my stylesheet, just one canvas with the 4 images I need.  I guess it's possible but I can't figure it out.  I'd appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a simple graphic which is merely a "number strip" of sorts. It's a good image to demonstrate the concept you're asking about and most importantly, I already had it created. Here it is...

[numbers http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/numbers.png](http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/numbers.png)

This image was made by combining six individual 40x40 icons. I used PS Elements to do it, but GIMP or many other image editors could accomplish the job. Our single bitmap consists of six individual images, referred to as "sprites." What we will do is manipulate the image to display only one sprite at a time, by adjusting the background-position-x CSS property (and by ensuring our "aperture" or display window is only large enough to reveal but one sprite).

Given the following javascript:

```
$( '#logo2' ).on( 'mouseover', function() {
    var current2 = $( '#toons2' ).css( "background-position" ).split( " " );
    current2[0] = parseInt( current2[0].replace( "px", "" ), 10 );
    current2[0] = ( ( current2[0] > -120 ) ? current2[0] - 40 : 0 );
    $( '#toons2' ).css( "background-position", current2[0] + "px 0" )
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="toons2"></div>
<div id="logo2">hover2</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#toons2 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: transparent url( 'img/image01.png' ) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

then we can expect each time we mouse over div#logo2 the background image of div#toons2 will be changed. (In this case, the first four icons will sequentially display and repeat.)

The height and width of div#toons2 is important: it must match the exact height and width of one single sprite (40x40). So, if we had a combined graphic of individual sprites which were each 35 pixels wide by 90 pixels tall for example, then we would need to set the height and width of div#toons2 for a width of 35 and height of 90. This is all very straightforward.

As for our javascript, all we're doing is adjusting the background-position-x value by -40 pixels each time we hover, because that's the width of each sprite. Initially, we see...

[one http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number1-open.png](http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number1-open.png)

Now, the first time we mouse over we will adjust the x position of our "number strip" by -40 pixels, effectively setting the CSS for div#toons2 as...

```
background-position: -40px 0;
```

which yields...

[two http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number2-open.png](http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number2-open.png)

The next time we mouse over, backgroundPositionX will be -80px, which would display as...

[three http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number3-open.png](http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number3-open.png)

Finally, setting background-position-x to -120px shows the fourth icon in the image, namely...

[four http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number1-closed.png](http://www.secretagentorange.com/_test/number1-closed.png)

Let's look at the javascript. This line:

```
var current2 = $( '#toons2' ).css( "background-position" ).split( " " );
```

gets the X and Y backgroundPosition values for div#toons2.

In our case, we are only concerned with the X value, as follows:

```
current2[0] = parseInt( current2[0].replace( "px", "" ), 10 );
```

Here, we're grabbing the first index, stripping out any expected suffix, and converting the string to an integer. Now that we have the numeric value, we can easily manipulate it.

In our example, we must move the graphic to the left 40 pixels to reveal each subsequent sprite, so we'll subtract 40 from our integer to do that. But since we only wish to see four images, in keeping with the poster's original conditions, we check to ensure we don't go too far. And if we've displayed the fourth sprite, we will reset the X value to zero. The next line does this:

```
current2[0] = ( ( current2[0] > -120 ) ? current2[0] - 40 : 0 );
```

Having arrived at our new X value, we just need to plug it into the backgroundPositionX property:

```
 $( '#toons2' ).css( "background-position", current2[0] + "px 0" )
```

where we build the string that defines the new value. (The second argument '0' is the Y position which requires no changes.)

That does it.

Here's the [fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/UxKyY)](http://jsfiddle.net/UxKyY/). It includes the original conditions as well as the suggested solution.